# Ionic deviceOrientation-Plugin returns always 0

Tags: android, ionic2, device-orientation

I am trying to implement to Ionic device-orientation plugin.
I've added this code to my App:

```
this.subscription = this.deviceOrientation.watchHeading({frequency: 1000}).subscribe(
function(data){
alert(data.magneticHeading)
}
);
```

And imported the plugin this way:

```
import {DeviceOrientation, DeviceOrientationCompassHeading} from '@ionic-native/device-orientation';
```

I am using the Android Emulator to test the orientation value. But a always get the value 0. 
I also ensured that the setting of the orientation works in Android Emulator (by using a compass-App)

Does anybody has an idea why the orientationValue doesn't change ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.